# Change a re-used cell's type?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have a grouped table of 2 sections.

The first section is only 1 cell and it is a specific subclass with XIB.  The rest of the cells in the table display basic data without XIB.

The issue I am having is when the very first cell goes to be re-used, the cell's subclass is obviously still that of the one that uses the XIB, so when I attempt to apply data to it, it doesn't have any of the proper labels etc in their locations.

I need to either ignore the first cell and keep using the second type of cell, or change the cell's type.

What is the best way to handle this situation, and how do you accomplish it?

ive tried

`if (cell == nil || [cell isKindOfClass:[InspectionMasterTableViewCell class]])` but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

The basic layout of my cellForRowAtIndexPath is this

```
if (indexPath.section == InspectionsMasterSectionData)
{
    // CREATE CELL
    static NSString *CellWithIdentifier = @"InspectionMasterTableViewCell";
    InspectionMasterTableViewCell *cell = (InspectionMasterTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellWithIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InspectionMasterTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return cell;
}
else
{
    static NSString *CellWithIdentifier = @"FormTableViewCell";
    FormTableViewCell *cell = (FormTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellWithIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil || [cell isKindOfClass:[InspectionMasterTableViewCell class]])
        cell = [[FormTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellWithIdentifier];

   //CELL DATA
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: edited to show you my general layout

Comment: Have you set the same reuse identifier "InspectionMasterTableViewCell" for the cell in InspectionMasterTableViewCell.xib?

Answer (score 3):

Typically, each type of cell should have it's own re-use identifier. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, ask for the type of cell you want by specifying the proper re-use identifier, then cast to the proper type.

Comment: That appears to be what i'm doing.  Yet every time the first cell would be re-used, the cell that appears is blank, like the data isn't being added correctly because of missing labels

Comment: @JMD, where are you adding the data? I don't see it above in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.